# Secure API request successful, otherwise rollback

Tags: node.js, express, database-design

I have two tables, user and user's role. The user role table will save user's role, each user has multiple roles. I have created two apis for deleting a user - one is delete the user based on the userId on user table, another is delete this user's roles on user role table.

```
DELETE /users/:uid
DELETE /user/:uid/roles/:roleId
```

How can I secure the two requests are sending correct both, if one faild, for example, the user has been deleted, but the request that delete his role faild, the both request actions will rollback.

I'm using node.js express and sequelize, I run two instances destory, but if the second one is faild, the first one does still run. It's not rollback

```
await User.destroy({where:userId});
await UserRole.destroy({where:userId});
```

How should I fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sequelize transaction` and with `Try and Catch` we can achieve managed transactions where we explicitly call `commit()` and `rollback()` like this :

```
let transaction;    

try {
  // get transaction
  transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

  // step 1
  await Model.destroy({where: {id}, transaction});

  // step 2
  await Model.create({}, {transaction});

  // step 3
  await Model.update({}, {where: {id}, transaction });

  // commit
  await transaction.commit();

} catch (err) {
  // Rollback transaction only if the transaction object is defined
  if (transaction) await transaction.rollback();
}
```